# PHP timestamp conversion with DateTime::createFromFormat()

Tags: php, timestamp

This code:

```
$timestamp = 1423522800;  // Timestamp for 2015-02-10
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $timestamp);

echo $date1->format('d/m/Y H:i') . "\n";
echo $date1->format('U') . "\n\n";

$date2 = new DateTime('2015-02-10');

echo $date2->format('d/m/Y H:i') . "\n";
echo $date2->format('U') . "\n";
```

Gives me this output:

09/02/2015 23:00
1423522800

10/02/2015 00:00
1423522800

What the hell is going on?

I think it's timezone related, but from the DateTime::createFromFormat() documentation:

> Note: The timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when
>   the time parameter either contains a UNIX timestamp (e.g. 946684800) or
>   specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).

I'm using PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5

Comment: Yes, it's time-zone related. `$date1` is created without any TZ assumptions, but once you start calling `format()`, you'll be implicitly applying TZ data, so your time-less date will get mangled into whatever DateTime is using for your TZ, as if the original date/time was UTC.

Comment: Did you set the default timezone ? `date_default_timezone_set($tz);`? I just ran it with `$tz="America/Los_Angeles"` and got 09/02/2015 23:00: 1423522800,  10/02/2015 00:00: 1423555200, respectively.

Comment: My default timezone is _Europe/Madrid_ but if I change it to UTC with `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')` at the begining of the script the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

When a DateTime object from a UNIX timestamp with

```
$timestamp = 1423522800;  // Timestamp for 2015-02-10
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $timestamp);
```

or

```
$date1 = new DateTime('@'.$timestamp);
```

or

```
$date1 = date_create('@'.$timestamp);
```

is created, the time zone of the object is always +00:00 or UTC. Even if a time zone is specified when the object is created, this is ignored when a timestamp is used.

```
$timestamp = 1423522800;  // Timestamp for 2015-02-10
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $timestamp, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid'));

var_dump($date1);
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-02-09 23:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}
```

To get the local time, the time zone has to be set after the DateTime has been created.

```
$date = date_create('@1423522800')
  ->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid'));

var_dump($date);
```

Now the object has the expected time and time zone.

```
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-02-10 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Madrid"
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to `DateTime::createFromFormat()` use `date_default_timzone_get()` on `format()`  without `setTimezone(...)` ?

Comment: As far as I know not. A time zone parameter and a current time zone in the date-expression are always ignored if the date-expression contains a UNIX timestamp.