# Output of date() and DateTime::format() differ, DateTime::format() ignores timezone

Tags: php, date

I've set the timezone of PHP to 'Europe/Berlin' in `php.ini`, which should be +1 to UTC (in winter).

When I output a Unix timestamp (UTC) to the user (with Apache and browser) by using `date()`, the timezone is used correctly. When I output the same timestamp with `DateTime::format()`, there is no timezone applied, until I set it explicitly with `DateTime::setTimezone()`.

**See the following example code:**

```php
<?php

$now = time();

// Verify Timezone
$tz = ini_get('date.timezone');
echo 'Timezone: ' . $tz  . '<br>';

// Using date
echo 'date(): ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $now) . '<br>';

// Using DateTime
$dt = new DateTime('@' . $now);
echo 'DateTime1: ' . $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '<br>';

// Setting DateTime timezone explicitly
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
echo 'DateTime2: ' . $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '<br>';
```

**Output:**

```
Timezone: Europe/Berlin
date(): 2020-12-09 15:31:32
DateTime1: 2020-12-09 14:31:32
DateTime2: 2020-12-09 15:31:32
```

Why is that? I can't see any hints in the docs that `DateTime::format()` ignores the timezone set in `php.ini` by default.

Comment: Do yourself a favor; set the server (including any databases, if applicable) to UTC, and handle timezone conversion when necessary in the code itself.

Comment: @ceejayoz That may be right in terms of architecture (and I'm doing that already) but does not help me with my question why the two functions behave differently.

Comment: Seems like `$dt = new DateTime('@' . $now);` coerces it into creating UTC. If you do `new DateTime()` it uses the configured timezone.

Comment: @El_Vanja I noticed that hint in the [__construct docs](https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.construct.php) but in my understanding shouldn't affect the output of `::format()`. But you're probably right. Seems like DateTime::format uses the timezone the object stored internally at construction time.

Comment: The `format` method works with underlying data. If that data is created with a UTC timezone, then that is what `format` will return.

Answer (score 2):

As @El_Vanja pointed out in the comments, the `DateTime` constuctor ignores the timezone when being set by unix timestamp ([see docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php))

The `::format()` method takes into regard what is set in the object (=UTC) and not what is set in `php.ini`.

Comment: It doesn't ignore the time zone (although that's what the docs say). A Unix timestamp is UTC by definition, so it uses that.

Comment: Even if a time zone is specified in the constructor when the object is created, this is ignored when a timestamp is used. see also answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437193/php-timestamp-conversion-with-datetimecreatefromformat/64992291#64992291